Stacking Vs Voting Vs Blending
I am working on an experiment with a dataset, where I compared the performance of stacking, blending, and voting using base models and logistic regression as my meta model. Although, voting seems to be the most simplest method - it somehow has the best result for my binary classification.
Is there any papers/information regarding how the three ensemble methods perform in relation to types of datasets, types of supervised learning (regression vs classification), etc? In practice is voting often used? From my knowledge most kaggle competitions use stacking instead of more simpler methods like voting.
